# How to write import statement when the scripts can be called from different locations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-module, python-packaging

Consider the following directory structure:

```
project/ 
    scripts/
        a1.py
        a2.py
    start.py
```

`start.py` depends on `a1.py` and `a1.py` in turn uses a function called `some_func` which is present in `a2.py`. Moreover, `a1.py` is also a standalone script and can be called independently. Now this gives rise two cases:

**Case 1**: (*Standalone script*)
I would import some_func as follows

`from a2 import some_func`

**Case 2**: (*Called from `start.py`*)

`from scripts.a2 import some_func`

**My Question**: What is the pythonic way of combining the two use cases?

*Possible Solution?*: Is this recommended or not?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from a2 import some_func
elif __name__ == "start":
    from scripts.a2 import some_func
```

Note: I am using python 3.x

Comment: What is the problem with calling `from a2 import some_func` in `a1` and `from a1 import some_func` in `start`?

Comment: You can use relative imports in a1.py, more about relative imports [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 1):

Pythonic way is create a package from your code and then use intra-package references in your code: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

```
from . import some_func  # from scripts in same folder
from .scripts import some_func  # from start.py
```

Also you will be able to use absolute paths (from package name) after packaging your solution and installing it, like:

```
# this will work from anywhere
from mypackage.scripts import some_func
```